# Implementing interface type to function type in Golang

Tags: go, interface

I have created few types including interface as:

```
// GetProfileHandlerFunc turns a function with the right signature into a get profile handler
type GetProfileHandlerFunc func(GetProfileParams, interface{}) middleware.Responder

// Handle executing the request and returning a response
func (fn GetProfileHandlerFunc) Handle(params GetProfileParams, principal interface{}) middleware.Responder {
    return fn(params, principal)
}

// GetProfileHandler interface for that can handle valid get profile params
type GetProfileHandler interface {
    Handle(GetProfileParams, interface{}) middleware.Responder
}
```

Now in my api implementation package. I am using a logic to handle the request parameters. I am trying to assign `GetProfileHandlerFunc` to another type since it implements `GetProfileHandler` interface as you can see above.

```
api.ProfileGetProfileHandler = profile.GetProfileHandlerFunc(func(params profile.GetProfileParams, principal *models.User) middleware.Responder {
     // contains logic to handle the request
}
```

Now I think I can do above logic. But I am getting type mismatch error.

> cannot convert func literal (type func(profile.GetProfileParams,
>   *"userproj/models".User)
>   middleware.Responder) to type profile.GetProfileHandlerFuncgo

Comment: Your error message does not match your code.

Comment: *"Now I think I can do above logic"* No you can *not*. `func(params profile.GetProfileParams, principal *models.User) middleware.Responder` is not the same as `func(GetProfileParams, interface{}) middleware.Responder`. That is: `*models.User` is not the same type as `interface{}`.

Comment: @mkopriva But If I have implemented the single method in a interface with my type then I can use the interface also. That's how io.Reader works because it implements basic Read method.

Comment: @Volker error message is for reference main question is Can implement the interface.

Comment: It doesn't matter what interface the `GetProfileHandlerFunc` type implements, the error is not saying anything about interfaces, it tells you that you cannot convert A to B, where A is the func literal `func(params profile.GetProfileParams, principal *models.User) middleware.Responder` and B is the func type `GetProfileHandlerFunc`.

Comment: ... It's the same as trying to do `int("hello world")`, you are doing conversion between two incompatible types.

Comment: @mkopriva you are right but I have seen same thing when people implements io.Reader or other readers in interface

Comment: @Himanshu. NO, you cannot have seen this because it is impossible in Go. See also https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. Go's type system does not work the way you think. `interface{}` does not mean "whatever" it means `interface{}` and only `interface{}`. You can **assign** anything to `interface{}` but as a type it is `interface{}` and _nothing_ _else_.

Comment: You've probably misunderstood what you've seen or the code was as well broken and would not compile just like yours.

Comment: @Volker what happens when you create a handler in which if you implement `ServeHTTP` it will implement the `Handler` interface and then you can use it in mux.

Comment: @Volker the issue was different because I have generated the code again and it is working now. But I do not the reason why it was not working before. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

the point is:
if you have a function like

```
func A(param interface{}) {}
```

you can pass anything to param when you make a call to function A. like

```
A(10)
A(true)
A(nil)
```

Because interface{} means everything. So your handle func definition:

```
type GetProfileHandlerFunc func(GetProfileParams, interface{}) middleware.Responder
```

means a function GetProfileHandlerFunc which takes two params, the first is of type GetProfileParams, the second is of type interface{}. That means second param canbe anything.

But

```
func(params profile.GetProfileParams, principal *models.User) middleware.Responder
```

means a function which takes two params, the first is of type GetProfileParams, the second is of type *models.User. So, do you think they are the same? No.

I need a function can take anything as second param,not a function who can only take User as second function.

When you call your handle

```
GetProfileHandlerFunc(params, 10) // this is ok
```

So is that ok for

```
func(params profile.GetProfileParams, principal *models.User) middleware.Responder
```

No.

The right way to do this is :

```
api.ProfileGetProfileHandler = profile.GetProfileHandlerFunc(func(params profile.GetProfileParams, principal interface) middleware.Responder {

     user:=principal.(*model.User) // watch this.
}
```